# How to know what queries django orm is creating while saving data?

Tags: django, postgresql

I'm new to django and dont know much about sql. I have made a model and its working fine. I'm saving data through django admin with no issues. However I have to save lots of data one by one. Is there a way to know what queries djano is creating when I click save button on django admin? I can dublicate that query and attach data with it.

I have installed django_debug_toolbar but even that is not showing sql queries when I save the data. Is there a way to see django orm sql queries WHILE saving the data? Can I log it into the terminal? I'm using postgresql.

Answer (score 1):

You have to configure either PostgreSQL server or Django to log your queries.

`postgresql.conf` example:

```
log_min_duration_statement = 0
```

Django `settings.py` example:

```python
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'simple': {
            'format': '%(asctime)s (%(process)d) %(levelname)s %(message)s',
        },  
    },  
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'simple',
        },  
        'file': {
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': '/tmp/mycoolapp.log',
            'formatter': 'simple',
        },  
    },  
    'loggers': {
        'django.contrib.admin': {
            'handlers': ['console', 'file'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
        },  
    },  
}
```